# "object not found" after install xampp

Tags: xampp

I have installed xampp and start in xampp control panel.when run my localhost, `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` in browser,
 it displays like "object not found", I referenced in stackoverflow site related to this post, and i followed but it didn't help.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you started the apache service ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen: Already i started apache and mysql service.

Comment: Is **localhost/xampp** running ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen: I click the start button in xampp control panel. plese see this link http://imgur.com/8tDJa5Y

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen: did you get my comment?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen: still 4 times reinstall xampp.. please share exact link to install xampp please..

Comment: I have updated the answer with the wikihow link, kindly check it

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen: already the port is 80,  now i changed to 8080. then only turn on apache otherwise won't turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the XAMPP Control Panel and start the Apache Service like the below given screen

[image]

Here is the full tutorial on XAMPP Installation

Wikihow tutorial - http://www.wikihow.com/Install-XAMPP-for-Windows

http://php.sysaxiom.com/install_linux.php

Comment: @someone: Can anybody help me?

Comment: The issue is you have installed the apache with the port which is already used. You need to uninstall the Xampp and install with different apache port no (rather than 8080)

Comment: I followed that link only..still  i didn't get it